# Xamarin - Entry SetImeActionLabel actonNext not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have two Entry field in Xamarin Forms. While running the app in android am getting "Done" in Keypad instead on Next. I need Next option for first Entry and Done option for next Entry in the Keypad.

I used CustomRenderer and made this

nativeEditText.SetImeActionLabel("Next",global::Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next);

This line doesn't go to the next Entry field...Pls help am new to Xamarin and c#

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Xamarin Forms intercepts the Done action and not the Next action.
You can do this to get the right behaviour by handing the Completed event:

```
userNameEntry.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    { passwordEntry.Focus(); };

passwordEntry.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        loginButton.Command.Execute(null);
    };
```

I haven't found any easy way to get both the correct label and the correct behaviour.

SetImeActionLabel correctly sets the ImeLabel property on the TextView, but both the action and the label seem to be ignored (at least on all devices and Android versions I have tested on).